# Showing even indexes in one column and odd indexes in another column using v-for

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, v-for

I want to show the even indexes of my array myArray:

```
   myArray: [{'label': 'hasan', 'value': 'hosein'},
            {'label': '1', 'value': '2'},
            {'label': 'gholi', 'value': 'gholam'},
            {'label': '3', 'value': '4'},
            {'label': 'an', 'value': 'goh'},
            {'label': '5', 'value': '6'},
            {'label': 'pashm', 'value': 'khar'},
            {'label': '7', 'value': '8'}]
```

in the right and odd indexes on the left column using v-for.

This is my HTML code:

```
      <div class="row" v-for="objData in myArray" :key="objData.label">
        // right column
        <div class="line col-2"></div>
        <div class="line col-3 "></div>
        // left column
        <div class="line col-2"></div>
        <div class="line col-3 "></div>
      </div>
```

I tried to separate the odd and even indexes into two new arrays and added a `<div>` above `<div class="row>` with a new `v-for` to loop through both arrays in my separate `<div>`s but it scrambled my array elements. So how can I show even indexes of `myArray` on the right and odd indexes on the left column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Spoiler:** I like the last one better*

You could either use this trick with `i` and `v-if`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       myArray: [{label:"hasan",value:"hosein"},{label:"1",value:"2"},{label:"gholi",value:"gholam"},{label:"3",value:"4"},{label:"an",value:"goh"},{label:"5",value:"6"},{label:"pashm",value:"khar"},{label:"7",value:"8"}]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />

<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <template v-for="(objData, i) in myArray" :key="objData.label">
        <div v-if="i%2">{{objData.label}}</div>
      </template>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <template v-for="(objData, i) in myArray" :key="objData.label">
        <div v-if="!(i%2)">{{objData.label}}</div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or separate your array in two in a `computed` prop, using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       myArray: [{label:"hasan",value:"hosein"},{label:"1",value:"2"},{label:"gholi",value:"gholam"},{label:"3",value:"4"},{label:"an",value:"goh"},{label:"5",value:"6"},{label:"pashm",value:"khar"},{label:"7",value:"8"}]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    splitArray() {
      const [ evens, odds ] = this.myArray.reduce((res, item, i) => {
        res[i % 2].push(item);
        return res;
      }, [[], []]);
      return { evens, odds };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />

<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div v-for="objData in splitArray.odds" :key="objData.label">
        {{objData.label}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div v-for="objData in splitArray.evens" :key="objData.label">
        {{objData.label}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... And if you want to go further, and not have to repeat yourself in the template:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       myArray: [{label:"hasan",value:"hosein"},{label:"1",value:"2"},{label:"gholi",value:"gholam"},{label:"3",value:"4"},{label:"an",value:"goh"},{label:"5",value:"6"},{label:"pashm",value:"khar"},{label:"7",value:"8"}]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    splitArray() {
      return this.myArray.reduce((res, item, i) => {
        res[1 - i % 2].push(item);
        return res;
      }, [[], []]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />

<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="(col, i) in splitArray" :key="`col-${i}`" class="col-sm">
      <div v-for="objData in splitArray[i]" :key="objData.label">
        {{objData.label}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution worked perfectly. However for the rest of them with computed property I got the error "Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined"

Comment: @seyet Cool. About the computed: maybe your `myArray` attribute is undefined when the component is created? If so, you could probably do `return (this.myArray || []).reduce(...)` to make sure it returns an Array

Comment: yes you are correct. I had changed the name of the array. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your data like this

```
var myArray = [
  { 
    left: {'label': 'hasan', 'value': 'hosein'},
    right: {'label': '1', 'value': '2'}
  }...
];
```

OR

use `display:grid` without `div.row`

```
<div v-for="(objData, index) in myArray" :key="objData.label" :class="['line', {col-2: index%2 === 1, col-3: index%2 === 0}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [this](https://codepen.io/lezojeda/pen/rNxdPwV)? Managed to separate the array in two columns but resorted to two v-for, maybe you won't like that. It uses less javascript than the other solutions proposed but with the trade-off of a more complicated HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

  <!-- Odd column -->
  <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <div v-for="(value, index) in myArray">
      <div v-if="index % 2 != 0">{{ value }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Even column -->
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
    <div v-for="(value, index) in myArray">
      <div v-if="index % 2 == 0">{{ value }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```